# Getting records of last week starting from Monday-Sunday from current date in php

Tags: php, sql, date

**Last week is starting from:**

13th May 2019(Monday) to 19th May 2019(Sunday)

**This week is starting from:**

20th May 2019(Monday) to 26th May 2019(Sunday)

In the database, I have records like this:

```
task_id   c_date
1         2019-05-14
2         2019-05-16 
3         2019-05-13
4         2019-05-17
5         2019-05-19
6         2019-05-21
7         2019-05-23
8         2019-05-24
9         2019-05-24
```

the excepted output will be like 1,2,3,4,5 records of the last week

**what I have tried:(approach 1st)**

```
       $dt = new DateTime;
       $dt->setISODate($dt->format('o'), $dt->format('W') - 1);
        $year = $dt->format('o');
        $week = $dt->format('W');


          $this_week = array();

           do {

              echo '<span>' . $dt->format('l') . " " . $dt->format('d M Y') . "</span></br>\n";
            // $date_sheet = $dt->format('Y-m-d'); 
            // array_push($this_week, $date_sheet);  

      $dt->modify('+1 day');


     } while ($week == $dt->format('W'));
```

**Output:**

```
Monday 13 May 2019
Tuesday 14 May 2019
Wednesday 15 May 2019
Thursday 16 May 2019
Friday 17 May 2019
Saturday 18 May 2019
Sunday 19 May 2019
```

I prefer this but the problem is I can't figure it out how to fetch record from this approach from DB, so I trying to find Alternative and I thought it much better but don't know the how to do that

**Alternative Approach (2nd):**

```
$now =date("d-m-Y");
select * from tasks where `c_date` = DATE_SUB('.$now.', INTERVAL 7 DAY )
```

Don't get anything I am dam sure I am doing totally in the wrong way.
Any help is Appreciated.

Comment: `$now` would need to be quoted but just use `now()` or `cur_date`. It should be `Y-m-d`.

Comment: I try this approach: SELECT * FROM tasks WHERE c_date >= DATEADD(day, -7, GETDATE())  But got error: DATEADD does not exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use something like (warning there are no checks for errors):

```
$dtFrom = new DateTime; // get current date
$dtTo = new DateTime;
// format for previous week (no previous year check)
$dtFrom->setISODate($dtFrom->format('o'), $dtFrom->format('W') - 1);
// do the same for end date range
$dtTo->setISODate($dtTo->format('o'), $dtTo->format('W') );
// subtract 1 day
$dtTo->sub(new DateInterval('P1D') );
// convert to iso date for database use
$dFrom = $dtFrom->format('y-m-d');
$dTo   = $dtTo->format('y-m-d');
```

The $dFrom and $dTo are date formats that could be used in a query

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE DateRange between $dFrom AND $dTo;
```